# PHP Mobile Camera Upload Not Working

Tags: php, file-upload, image-uploading

I have been working on this for a few days now, looking on previous questions/answers on here from other people and I have yet to find an answer. The idea behind this is to allow a mobile camera to upload a photo, compress it, store it and record the name of the file in the database.

If I use this code on my PC, it works, no problem. If I use my phone camera, I get either Page not working - ERROR 500 or the form says it has uploaded and I check, the database has the name, but on the server, 'File Not Found'. I have also tried uploading a saved image from my phone and the same happens.

Below is the PHP Script:

```
$db = new PDO('mysql:host=host;dbname=db', 'user', 'pass');

function compress($source, $destination, $quality) {

    $info = getimagesize($source);

    if($info['mime'] == 'image/jpeg') {
        $image = imagecreatefromjpeg($source);
    } else if($info['mime'] == 'image/gif') {
        $image = imagecreatefromgif($source);
    } else if($info['mime'] == 'image/png') {
        $image = imagecreatefrompng($source);
    }

    imagejpeg($image, $destination, $quality);

    return $destination;

}

if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {

    $target = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/images/uploads/'
    $target = $target . basename($_FILES['file']['name']);

    $photo_name = ($_FILES['file']['name']);
    $imageFileType = pathinfo($target, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
    $file = $photo_name;

    $query = "INSERT INTO jrtwall_images (imgurl) VALUES ('$file')";
    $result = $db->query($query);

    if($result && compress($_FILES['file']['tmp_name'], $target, 50)) {

        header("Location: /?pid=1&success=1");
        exit();

    } else {

        header("Location: /?pid=1&error=1");
        exit();

    }

}
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<form action="core/engines/upload-v2.eng.php" method="post" autocomplete="off" enctype="multipart/form-data">

    <input type="file" name="file" />
    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Upload &amp; Send" />

</form>
```

`print_r($_FILES['file']);` shows:

```
Array([name] => 15316729868972697354228305840469.jpg [type] => image/jpeg [tmp_name] => /tmp/phpAvNZZF [error] => 0 [size] => 4649129)
```

Any help what-so-ever would be greatly appreciated. I'm running PHP 5.6.

**Things I Have Tried:**

- Enabling Cross Origin
- Increasing both Upload and Post size limits in my php.ini
- Uploading with out the compression function (Works, but I NEED the compression)
- Adding 'capture' and 'image/*' to the input on the form
- Checking `$_FILES` array for errors, None/Error 0
- Adding $db (connection) to the Compress method
- Tried code on XAMPP and it worked after changing `$target` to `$target = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"].'/images/uploads/';` however, the tweak did not work once uploaded to the live server, still get ERROR 500. (Awaiting tech support to send me a copy of the server error log as I can't access it through my FTP or cPanel).
- Tried upgrading to PHP 7, 7.1, 7.2. No luck so reverted back to PHP 5.6.

Comment: In your code you doing no checks, so it will insert the row when it fails. You need to do more. Check the servers error log for the reason it 500's

Comment: @LawrenceCherone Thanks for pointing that out, I will definately add more checks.

Comment: For starters, you've a variable scope issue; that's most likely "thee" problem here, seeing your *"Uploading with out the compression function (Works, but I NEED the compression)"* . Add the connection to the method or make it global. That will most likely solve your issue.

Comment: @FunkFortyNiner I'm confused with your comment... Are you saying add my database connection to the code? If you are, I do have it in the code above the compress function, but for security I took it out but forgot to add a demo variable to show it is there. I'll add that on to the question. But is that what you meant?

Comment: no, add the connection to the method. I.e.: `function compress($source, $destination, $quality, $db)`.

Comment: Just tried that, it didn't work...

Comment: UPDATE: I have tried the code on xampp and it worked after a tweak. I uploaded the tweak and it's still not working on the live server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have fixed it. When I said I changed the Post and Upload size, I didn't think about increasing the memory_limit...

The answer to this is to change the memory_limit to 128M.

Answer (score 0):

I resolved this issue by changing the configuration of the server, please change relatively.

```
post_max_size = 20M
memory_limit = 2048M
```